# How to run android application only when connected to certain networks or VPN?

Tags: android, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager

Is there a way to restrict running of the app to the server it connects if it only connects through certain networks or VPN (such as eduroam). Is this a good way to restrict an app to run only at certain locations(i.e when connected to a network). Are there any other ways to regionally restrict the app to run only at selected locations?

Comment: you can calculate current location for application and calculate distance from that locations to check that the application is in particular area or not

Comment: you can use android geofences here is the link:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing